# Escaping single quotes not working for data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have a javascript array, which includes strings with escaped single quotes (`\'`). I want to include that array in the data attribute of a new element I `.append()` to the body.

```
var data = ['I\'m confused'];

$('body').append('<div data-data=\'' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\'></div>');

console.log($('div').data('data')); // -> "[\"I"
```

Problem: when reading the data attribute, the array is corrupted (`"[\"I"`).

Answer (score 2):

`\` is not an escape character in HTML. So the `'` in `\'` **will** terminate your attribute value that is delimited with `'` characters.

Don't try to manually escape strings and mash them together to create HTML.

It is error prone and hard to maintain.

Use DOM features (or jQuery APIs that wrap around them) instead.

```js
var data = ['I\'m confused'];

const div = $('<div />').attr('data-data', JSON.stringify(data));

$('body').append(div);

console.log($('div').data('data'));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```